# On Hilbert Class Polynomial

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, math-software, class-field-theory, sagemath

Is there any open source software  which computes Hilbert Class polynomial of an imaginary quadratic fields?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sage supports this function, i.e.

> hilbert_class_polynomial(-71);

You can try this online for free: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/

The algorithm of Sage, written in pseudo-code, goes as follows

[image]

In general, one computes
$$H_D(X)=\prod_{i=1}^h (X- j (\mathfrak{a}_i))$$
where $\mathfrak{a}_i$ ranges over the representatives of the class group. In the quadratic case, there is an easy way to find a set of representatives for the class group. This approach makes use of the theory of primitive reduced quadratic forms and the bijection between the *ideal class group* and *form class group* (see Cox §2 and §7). The above equation then becomes
$$H_D(X) = \prod_{[a,b,c] \in Cl(D)} \left( X- j\left(\frac{-b+i \sqrt{d}}{2a}\right) \right)$$
where $Cl(D)$ is the set of all reduced quadratic forms of discriminant $D$. The degree of $H_D(X)$ equals the class number. By iterating through all reduced forms of discriminant $D$, and computing a numerical value of the corresponding $j$-value, we get a simple method for constructing the polynomial $H_D(X)$. However, when calculating the $j$-value there might be a computational error. But since the polynomial has integer coefficients, this small error can be "recovered" by rounding to the nearest integers.

Comment: @ynnickvda,Thank you very much for providing sage on-line,which I didn't know,  I had studied the algorithm from Cohen's Book, also in NZMATH, some times it doesn't give the answer

Comment: @ynnickvda,Similarly is there any algorithm to find the ray class field mod$\mathfrak{m}$, please let me know

Comment: @ynnickvda how do we evaluate $j\left(\frac{-b+i \sqrt{d}}{2a}$ over $j( sqrt{d})$ if you know please let me know, Thank you in advance

Comment: the $j$-function can be evaluated through its $q$-expansion (cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#The_q-expansion_and_moonshine )